# JSF/Primefaces: Update Dialog not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `dataTable` with a `commandButton` in each `row`. If I click the `commandButton` a `dialog` should open with some more details one the selected row.

```
<p:commandButton
                        update="mainForm:myDialog"
                        action="#{bean.fetchData(user)}"
                        oncomplete="PF('myDialog').show();"
                        title="Details"
                    />
```

This is the `fetchData()` method in the `bean`:

```
 public void fetchData(user) {
        this.events = this.db.fetchDataForUser(user);
    }
```

The dialog:

```
<p:dialog
    header="Details"
    id="myDialog"
    modal="true"
    resizable="false"
    width="1000px"
    height="700px"
>
    <p:dataTable
        value="#{bean.events}"
        var="event"
    >
        <p:column
            headerText="Event"
            style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"
            width="auto"
        >
            <h:outputText
                value="#{event.eventType}"
            />
        </p:column>


       ....


    </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

The idea is that, when the `commandButton` is pressed, `fetchData()` gets executed and sets the `events` list. After that the `dialog` opens and displays the `events`.
But it's not working. 
Before `fetchData` is called, the `getter` executes multiple times.
Then `fetchData()` is getting called as expected and sets the `events` list. But when the `getter` for the `events` is getting called again, `events` is still `null`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. For example, for all we know, your bean scope might be wrong.

Comment: Or there are other invisible typo's. And improve your title... aggording to https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging you should not prepend titles with 'tags' and changing dialog to p:dialog is also better. But then the title is 'bad' ('not working' is not 'smart'...)  So try to narrow things down and improve your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow these steps and  examine example from PrimeFaces showcase

- First, put an object in your bean as selectedUser.
- Then, You have to set selectedUser. You can use ***setPropertyActionListener*** for it.
- Then, you can call your method in dialog. Your method will be like this

  public void fetchData() {
    this.events = this.db.fetchDataForUser(this.selectedUser);
  }

You can find a solution in [PrimeFaces - Showcase - DataTable - Selection](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

```
<p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars1}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Basic
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="pi pi-search" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

We have to set selected object with ***setPropertyActionListener***, after than we can fetch data according to it in dialog.

```
<p:dialog header="Car Info" widgetVar="carDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" columnClasses="label,value">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.brand}-big.gif"/> 
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Id:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.id}" />

            <h:outputText value="Year" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.year}" />

            <h:outputText value="Color:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.color}" style="color:#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.color}"/>

            <h:outputText value="Price" />
            <h:outputText value="$#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar.price}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

In bean,

```
@Named("dtSelectionView")
@ViewScoped
public class SelectionView implements Serializable {

    private Car selectedCar;

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }
}
```